# Why does fermat little theorem work?

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, exponential-function

I'm trying to understand intuitively why `(p-1)th` power of any integer(not divisible by p) leaves a remainder of 1 when divided by p. (where p is a prime number)

I understand that `p` times any integer becomes a `multiple of p` and would be divided `p`. Similarly, can I understand the growth of the exponential function and reason why `p-1 th power of any integer is always congruent to 1 mod p`.

Comment: Firstly, it's not *any* integer. It's only integers not divisible by $p$. Secondly, you might want to understand the variant of Fermat's little theorem which says that $a^p\equiv a\pmod p$ (which *does* work for all $a$. This one can be seen easily from the formula $(a+b)^p\equiv a^p+b^p\pmod p$, which follows from binomial expansion, and induction.

Comment: https://primes.utm.edu/notes/proofs/FermatsLittleTheorem.html

Comment: Seconding @Wojowu. Binomial theorem is your friend here. Show it for $a = 1$ then for the induction hypothesis assume it holds for $k$ then prove for $k+1$ with binomial theorem. There is a secondary result built into this that you need which is that $p$ divides $\binom{p}{m}$ for any $0< m < p$ where $p$ is prime. Primality is key here and it's used in a subtle way.

Comment: you need nothing but the fact that the multiples of a are coprime to p as in the proof in my link.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee That's a _very_ nice way to do it. Definitely one of the cuter proofs I've seen for a simply-stated result.

Comment: As for building intuition., notice that if you have a prime $p$ and a number $a$ which is coprime to $p$, then $a^2$ will also be coprime to $p$.  So too will $a^3$ be coprime to $p$ and so on...  Now... eventually the remainders of $a^n$ modulo $p$ will eventually have to repeat, and if they did repeat it would need to be in a predictable pattern.  Fermat's little theorem and Lagrange's theorem helps explain what types of patterns we can expect.

Comment: @Wojowu Thanks, missed to put that down - have corrected it.

Answer (score 7):

Your intuition to understand this result by analogy to a multiple of $p$ being divisible by $p$ will not work in this case. The standard explanation runs like this: For any number $a$ which is not divisible by $p$, we know that $a\equiv A \bmod p$ where $1\le A \le (p-1)$. Next, we look at the products $1\cdot A,\ 2\cdot A,\ 3\cdot A,\dots (p-1)\cdot A$. There are $(p-1)$ such products, and none of them have any factors of $p$.

We look at those products and ask if any two of them can have the same value $\bmod p$. The answer is no, because if they did their difference would have to be $0\bmod p$. That is, $c_2\cdot A-c_1\cdot A \equiv 0 \bmod p \iff c_2=c_1$ and that is not the case. We have $(p-1)$ distinct products having values between $1$ and $(p-1)$, so by the pigeonhole principle, each value must occur once. We don't know which product corresponds to which value, but we don't need to.

We simply multiply the residues of the products $1$ through $(p-1)$ to obtain $(p-1)!$, and then products $1\cdot A$ through $(p-1)\cdot A$ themselves to obtain $(p-1)!A^{p-1}$, keeping in mind that these two numbers will be equivalent $\bmod p$, viz $$(p-1)!\equiv (p-1)!A^{p-1} \bmod p$$

Since $(p-1)!$ is coprime to $p$, we can divide through to remove it leaving the desired result $$1\equiv A^{p-1}\equiv a^{p-1} \bmod p$$

Answer (score 4):

It might help you to study a few specific cases.

For example, $a = 10$, $p = 7$. We see that $10^6 = 1000000$ and 999999 divided by 7 is 142857.

But let's work through this example using smaller numbers. Obviously $10^2 = 100$. But 98 is a multiple of 7, which means that $10^2 \equiv 2$ $\pmod 7$. And 10 itself is $3 \pmod 7$, so we can calculate $10^3 \equiv ?$ $\pmod 7$ as $2 \times 3 = 6$. And then $10^4 \equiv 6 \times 3 \equiv 4 \pmod 7$. Next we have $10^5 \equiv 4 \times 3 \equiv 5 \pmod 7$.

Lastly, $10^6 \equiv 5 \times 3 \equiv 1 \pmod 7$, 
which we had already confirmed. I chose this example because $10^n$ modulo 7 takes on every value from 0 to 6 except 0. That's not always the case, but it helps to show which values can't be taken on.

Now consider instead $p = 14$, which is clearly not prime, and $a$ the same as before. You might be aware of the fact that 14 is not a Fermat pseudoprime. But much more importantly in this example, $\gcd(10, 14) = 2$, so we will see that $10^{13} \not\equiv 1 \pmod{14}$.

Then we see that $10 \equiv 10 \pmod{14}$, which is obvious but needs to be said, because $10^2 \equiv 2 \pmod{14}$ just the same as modulo 7. Then $10^3 \equiv 6 \pmod{14}$, $10^4 \equiv 4 \pmod{14}$, $10^5 \equiv 12 \pmod{14}$, $10^6 \equiv 8 \pmod{14}$, $10^7 \equiv 10 \pmod{14}$, $10^8 \equiv 2 \pmod{14}$... whoa, we're back to 2.

The common divisor between 10 and 14 is 2, which means that odd numbers (coprime to 2) can't occur in $10^n \equiv ? \pmod{14}$.

I hope this helps you understand. You might also want to work through examples where $p$ is composite but nonetheless coprime to $a$. Probably hold off on numbers like 341, 561 for now, though.